# is a continuously differentiable function holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let Ω be a domain in  $ \Bbb C$, and $f : Ω → \Bbb C$ be a $C^1$ function such that
$$
i\frac{∂f}{∂x} =\frac{∂f}{∂y}.
$$
Is f holomorphic?

I think f is holomorphic because it is $C^1$ and $\frac{∂f}{∂x}, \frac{∂f}{∂y}$ exists. But how do I show it?

Comment: By that argument, the real part function would be holomorphic. But it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

If we rewrite $f$ in real and imaginary parts as $f=u+iv$. Then the equation says that $$i\frac{\partial u+iv}{\partial x}= \frac{\partial u+iv}{\partial y}.$$ The real and imaginary parts of this equation must be equal so
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}= \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$$ and $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}= -\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}.$$ This is the cauchy riemann equations, and since the partial derivatives are continuous the functions is indeed holomorphic.

Answer (score 0):

Write $f=u+iv$ with u and v real $C^1$ functions. Then $iu_x-v_x=u_y+iv_y$. Therefore $u_x=v_y$ and $-v_x=u_y$, that is, the Cauchy-Riemann condition holds.